# What is the best and fastest way to load external geometries into Three.js, without impacting on UI

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, loader, web-worker

Currently I'm loading a lot of .obj-Files (together 20MB) into Three.js. When the files are loaded everything is working fine, but the Problem is, that Three.JS needs about 25 seconds to load and process the data and the user can not interact with the Page, which is very anoying.
The files just contain geometry, wihtout animation and materials, so I was wondering if there are better Methods to load geometries into Three.JS. I read a lot about webworkers and buffered geometry, but until now I couldn't find a clear solution to my problem. 
I hope someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`examples/js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js) as that packs the objects very efficiently. You can convert the objects with the tool you can find at http://openctm.sourceforge.net/

I don't think you can avoid the UI freezing for a bit as the models are inserted in the scene, but OpenCTM should really reduce the problem. There is a [`examples/js/loaders/ctm/CTMWorker.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ctm/CTMWorker.js) as well.

Live examples: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm and http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm_materials

Answer (score -2):

I'm just beginning three.js

But I think this may help you

http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Loaders/Loader
the .addStatusElement() can be used as a debugging tool for the loading of geometries

In relation to cutting down load time, this site explains  "Drawing multiple objects using a single draw call" (but doesn't use .obj files)
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/#toc-efficientwebgl

In regard to "buffered geometry" the answer to the following question give a concise outline of buffered geometry, in regard to "Verold Studio" http://www.verold.com/

[Fastest method to load a large number of objects in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879675/fastest-method-to-load-a-large-number-of-objects-in-three-js)

Thank you for your advice @Armam
I undeleted my answer just to thank you for your advice. (you can delete this comment)
If its not too much trouble could you advise me how to reformat this question, in a more concise matter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312778/i-need-help-understanding-the-math-in-a-three-js-simple-animation

@spencer7593 Thanks for your opinion, I haven't yet mastered asking good question, but I really appreciate your advice.